# How to get the Same price for grouped items

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

This code works perfect for Items that have the same address.
If they have same addressId, then they are grouped together under that one address.

5 items same address that shows up fine, but it is placing the same shipping fee for each item.

Need to only show the same as address, only one shipping fee for Same Group of items.
Please help, I have been trying at this for past two-days..Cannot figure out how to return the one shipping fee for group of items.

var itemshippingGroup, should be grouped shipping fee, display, only one of those fees, not each 5-items as separate fee.

See code below

```
//cart rows
var numofItems = productCart.length;
var productSubTotal = 0, shipping = 0;



var retriveAdd = getStoredData(address_cookie_name);
//alert(retriveAdd);
var productAddress = $.parseJSON(retriveAdd);
var k = 0;
for(var ad in productAddress){
    var j = 0;
    for(var i in productCart) {
        var ship = 0;
        var value = productCart[i];
        var addressId = productCart[i].addressId;
        var shippingId = parseFloat(productCart[i].shippingmethod).toFixed(2);
        if(ad == addressId){
            var item = parseInt(i)+1;

            var address = productAddress[productCart[i].addressId];
            var itemshipping = parseFloat(productCart[i].shippingmethod).toFixed(2);

            var fName = '', lName = '';
            if(address){
                fName = address.firstName;
                lName = address.lastName;
                itemAddress = address.address1+" <br> "+ address.city+","+address.state+" "+address.zipcode;
                if(addressId == shippingId){
                    var itemshippingGroup = shippingId;
                }
            }



            // Sub Total
            productSubTotal = productSubTotal + ((parseFloat(value.productPrice) + parseFloat(value.productTax)) * value.productQty);
            var trStyle = "style='background-color:#FFFFFF;'";
            if(k%2 == 0){
                trStyle = "style='background-color:#F1F1F1;'";
            }                           
            cart_html += '<tr id="cart_row_'+i+'" class="cart_row" '+trStyle+'>';
            cart_html += '<td class="confirm-product"><span class="clearfix first_item last_item"><img src="'+value.productImage+'"   alt="" title="'+value.productName+'" class="cart-images"></td>';
            cart_html += '<td>'+value.productName+'<br>'+fName+' '+lName+'</td>';
            if(j == 0){
                cart_html += '<td>'+itemAddress+'</td>';
            }else{
                cart_html += '<td> </td>';
            }
            j++;
            cart_html += '<td>'+currencySymbol+''+parseFloat(value.productPrice).toFixed(2)+'</td>';
            cart_html += '<td>'+currencySymbol+''+parseFloat(value.productTax)+'</td>';
            cart_html += '<td class="itemshipping">'+currencySymbol+' '+itemshipping+'</td>';

            //cart_html += '<td>'+currencySymbol+' '+itemshipping+'</td>';

            cart_html += '<td>'+currencySymbol+' '+ ((parseFloat(value.productPrice) + parseFloat(value.productTax))*value.productQty).toFixed(2)+'</td>';
            //cart_html += '<td><a href="#" id="delete_prod_id'+i+'" class="close delete_product_from_cart" title="Delete">&times;</a></td>';

            cart_html += '</tr>';
            checkButton(value.uProductID);
            total_items += value.productQty;

            shipping += parseFloat(productCart[i].shippingmethod);
        }
    }
    k++;
}
```

Comment: How about a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something?

Comment: And what the desired output should look like.

Comment: I got the Fixe Fellas. I will post the answer. Thank you for assistance..